# Show by default first card for foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach, invision-power-board

I have some HTML

```
<ul class='ipsList_inline newClass' id='community_app_menu'>
<foreach loop="$pages as $page">
<li class='map_{$page['map_id']}'><a>{$page['map_title']}</a></li>
</foreach>
</ul>
```

This give me header
Card #1 Card #2 Card #3

I would like to add to each result (foreach) an iframe to show by default for one card(always first) and the other iframes (default hidden) shows by clicking on the card.

I do not know where to start and what to use, php java? I would be grateful for examples, solutions etc.

Comment: What language uses the `<foreach/>` tag in your code sample?

Comment: Added the tag which actually gives a clue to the uneducated reader...

Answer (score 1):

Although I will not give you a solution by using the IPB's proprietary syntax, I will use PHP code to illustrate the implementation principle. You may see the working sample on [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xv7-zsm).

jQuery is also used for handling the `iframe`s' visibility.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Script Execution</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(id) {
            $('iframe[id^="frame_"]').hide();
            $("#frame_" + id).show();
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $pages=array(
      array('map_title'=>'PHP','map_id'=>1),
      array('map_title'=>'HTML','map_id'=>2)
    );
    ?>
    <ul class='ipsList_inline newClass' id='community_app_menu'>
        <?php
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
        ?>
        <li style="display:inline;">
            <a id="link_<?php echo($page['map_id']);?>" onclick=
            "show(<?php echo($page['map_id']);?>);"><?php echo $page['map_title']?></a>
        </li><?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul><?php
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
    ?><iframe height="500px" id="frame_<?php echo($page['map_id']);?>"
    name="frame_<?php echo($page['map_id']);?>" src=
    "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=<?php echo($page['map_title']);?>"
    width="100%"
    <?php 
      if ($page['map_id'] != 1) { echo "style='display:none'"; }
    ?>
    ></iframe> <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```